# Is “Compete to get scraps from a shrinking pot” a set phrase, or President Obama’s ad hoc turn of phrase?

Tags: idioms, word-usage

In the New York Times’ interview to President Obama in Galesburg, Ill. on July 28 (http://www.nytimes.com/2013/07/28/us/politics/obama-says-income-gap-is-fraying-us-social-fabric.html?hp), Mr. Obama said;

> “Racial tensions won’t get better; they may get worse, because people
>   will feel as if they’ve got to **compete** with some other group **to get
>   scraps from a shrinking pot**,” Mr. Obama said. “If the economy is
>   growing, everybody feels invested. Everybody feels as if we’re rolling
>   in the same direction.”

Is “Compete to get scraps from a shrinking pot” a set phrase, or just President Obama’s ad hoc turn of phrase?

We have Japanese expression- 蟻がたかるように- to compete to get scraps like the swarm of ants for everybody swarming about marginal merits. 
Is there any alternative English idiom or phrasal expression corresponding to “Compete to get scraps from a shrinking pot”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost certainly a unique turn of phrase.  That said "shrinking pot" used in reference to a diminishing resource is a commonly used in American English.  One way to approach problems of this nature is to use a search engine to determine how common the usage is.  Some would call this "data mining"  There are only 633 hits for the exact phrase you asked about and the majority of them seem to reference the President Obama's remark. In contrast, a search for "shrinking pot" earns     17 000 hits and is used outside the context of his remarks.

Comment: In order to improve the credibility of an answer, it's always a good idea to mention not only the source but also to provide a link, whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, *shrinking pot* is used from time to time, but I think [*shrinking pie*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shrinking%20pot,shrinking%20pie&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) is heard more often. In both cases, the word "shrinking" refers to an economic condition, where the resources needed for prosperity get progressively smaller, thereby making it harder to attain wealth or even eke out a middle-class standard of living.

In U.S. politics, allusions to a proverbial "pot" – at least, privately-owned pots, filled with a chicken or two – go back at least as far as the Herbert Hoover campaign:

> Secretary of Commerce Herbert Hoover — a symbol for the new prosperity — was elected to the presidency in a landslide win in November [1928] on the promise of more to come: [two chickens in every pot](http://books.google.com/books?id=6DHlQJcMpBQC&pg=PA90&dq=%22two%20chickens%20in%20every%20pot%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=G9_0Ucb-OIzs8gSz-4CgBQ&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22two%20chickens%20in%20every%20pot%22&f=false), and two cars in every garage.

although [this resource](http://books.google.com/books?id=ACB81ZeNN5sC&pg=PA114&dq=%22two%20chickens%20in%20every%20pot%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=49_0UaiwC4XK9QT4zoCYAQ&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22two%20chickens%20in%20every%20pot%22&f=false) claims that Hoover never used the phrase directly, and attributes that phrase's origin to a French king in the late 1500s.

That said, the phrase you quote is alluding to a *community pot*, not the one found the family kitchen.

Getting back to your question, I would say that *compete to get scraps from a shrinking pot* is not an established idiom; however, it does use well-worn political language, and a metaphor is that is hardly unfamiliar to American ears.

Answer (score 0):

The most common U.S. idiom for the idea underlying "competing to get scraps from a shrinking pot" would probably be "fighting over the crumbs," the idea being that one or more powerful individuals or entities have taken the loaf (of bread) and left nothing but crumbs behind for the weaker to compete for.

Presumably, that idiom is so familiar (and perhaps hackneyed) that President Obama didn't want to invoke it. As other answerers have said, "competing to get scraps from a shrinking pot" is not an established idiomatic phrase in the United States.